# Why is it errorlevel 0 even if string is not found?

Tags: batch

If I run this code:

```
:loop
(type "File" | findstr Idle) > nul 2>&1
timeout 1
if errorlevel 1 goto loop
```

Then if the string "Idle" cannot be found within File, it will start over at "loop" and keep doing so until "Idle" is found at which point it will move down further in the code. This is all well and good, and if my code were structured so that this would be at the bottom of the code rather than the top, things would be ok here, but I need this to be the first command (so if Idle is found, repeat this loop, if idle is not found, move down)

But when I run this code:

```
:loop
(type "File" | findstr Idle) > nul 2>&1
timeout 1
if errorlevel 0 goto loop
```

It will always start over at "loop" regardless of whether or not the string "Idle" can be found.

I really need to be able to run a command if the string is found (rather than if the string is not found (I am not planning to use "goto" here, I need to run specific commands (like "goto") when "Idle" is found, and another set of commands when it is not found, so I need two valid errorlevels, or an alternative).

Why doesn't this work, and what other way is there for me to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read some documentation. You can start by typing `help if` or `if /?` from the command line, and if you read carefully, you will see one problem with your logic.

`IF ERRORLEVEL 0` means "return TRUE if ERRORLEVEL is >=0". This will always be true after running FINDSTR.

If you did not have the TIMEOUT before your IF, then you could simply use the IF NOT ERRORLEVEL condition.

```
:loop
(type "File" | findstr Idle) > nul 2>&1
if not errorlevel 1 goto loop
```

But the logic is destroyed when you add the TIMEOUT command because it clears the ERRORLEVEL to 0. So you must save the value to your own variable before running TIMEOUT.

```
:loop
(type "File" | findstr Idle) > nul 2>&1
set err=%errorlevel%
timeout 1
if %err% == 0 goto loop
```

But I would use `&&` instead:

```
:loop
type "File" | findstr Idle >nul 2>nul && (timeout 1 & goto :loop)
```

Or better yet:

```
:loop
findstr Idle "File" 2>nul >nul && (timeout 1 & goto :loop)
```

Comment: if not errorlevel 1 gives me the same result as errorlevel 0 (e.g. always passes) I had actually already tried this. Your alternative solution works pretty great though +1.

Comment: @Cestarian - No, IF ERRORORLEVEL 0 is true if ERRORLEVEL >=0, while IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 is true if ERRORLEVEL < 1.

Comment: Yes, and thanks to your note about **help if** I was able to find out that errorlevel can be treated as any other variable, and I also saw that indeed errorlevel operates as you say (if errorlevel 0 is true if errorlevel >=0). But this doesn't change the fact that "if not errorlevel 1 goto loop" is not working. I am using echo to tell me what the errorlevel is, and for me it won't pass through this statement even if errorlevel is 1. If you find a way that does indeed work (utilizing errorlevel), I will accept this answer.

Comment: damn man, it is exhibiting really weird behavior, I've tried a bunch of things. For example, **if %errorlevel% neq 1 goto loop** it will go through even if errorlevel is 1 (as in goto loop). However if I do **neq 0** it will continue below the loop every time (even if errorlevel is 1). Is it not doing this to you?

Comment: @Cestarian - it was the TIMEOUT command clearing the ERRORLEVEL. I've updated my answer. Also, you might consider removing your downvote from http://stackoverflow.com/a/13476936/1012053 (I'm assuming that was you)

Comment: ah, there we go. Thanks! And yes it was me, but that really doesn't work. I'll check again though and if I really did type something wrong I'll remove it (even turn it into an upvote)

Comment: Just one qualification: `if errorlevel 0` is _always_ true, not only after running `findstr`, since the returned value is between `0` and `255`.

Comment: @AFH - Not quite. ERRORLEVEL can be negative, and the range is -32768 - 32767. I'm not aware of any MS commands that return negative values, but some programs do. For example, Oracle uses negative error numbers that can be passed back as an ERRORLEVEL. And user supplied batch code with EXIT /B can return negative values.

Comment: @dbenham - Sorry, you're quite right. It used to be the case that only the bottom 8 bits of any return code were saved in `errorlevel`, but that is no longer the case. I didn't notice the change.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution eventually. (Only works because the string is the first line in my file)

```
:loop
set /p var=<File
timeout 1
if "%var%"=="Idle" goto loop
```

This worked for me, but I'd still like an answer to why errorlevels aren't working as advertised, or if I am just misunderstanding them (correct answer will go to whoever explains why the code in the original question doesn't work)

Comment: This only works if "Idle" is the first line in your file, which is not implied by your question.

Comment: @dbenham Yeah it does, this was never a problem though, and like I said in my answer, this is not exactly a perfect answer to my question.